# Text over image in Uiview

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uitextview

[image]sorry, if this might been asked before.

I am laying out a viewcontroller for a new app. It will include a photo (UIImageview) which fills the nearly all of the screen and it should include a scrollable UITextview which should fill the bottom right corner of the screen and including a description of the photo.

So i have two views over one space and i would like to give the Textview priority over the UIimage. Is there any other way then reducing "Alpha" of the UIImage to make the Textview visible ? Tinkered around with Conten Hugging Priority and Content Compression ... to no avail.

Any help  would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: So, i would look at adding the uitextview to the uiimageview by doing this UIImageView * imageView   ..... [imageView addSubview:YOUR_UITEXTVIEW]; this is how i resolve this same thing and then size your uitextview using autolayout constrants after setting the frame of the imageView, this will allow you to resize the textview in the coordinate space of the uiimageview. THEN, i would sample the color of the image that is behind the UITextview and then only use the compliementary color for the font of the UITextview so the font color changes according to the colors of the image

Comment: as in blue color image yeilds orange color text, purple image yields yellow text, red color image yields green text, and vice versa.

Comment: if you'd like an example i can provide one, in fact ,i can do the entire uiview subcass in about 30 mins or less, except for the color compliment effct, that would take about 10 more minutes. but I'm not going to post anything unless you understand what I'm telling you about subviews of a subview with autolayout constratins.

Comment: Thanks Larcerax, will try this tomorrow.. Sounds compromising

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make sure text is easily readable over any image, I suggest setting a background of color rgba(.2, .2, .2, .8) or something similar and then using a white font color.

Comment: Without reducing Alpha on the image to 0,65 the UItextview remains invisible

Comment: Why don't you use bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view method to make sure the UITextField is on top?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for trying to help me out... I have found the solution... It is perfectly ok to overlay Views in Interfacebuilder but then it is imperative to use a background color for the overlaying textview with reduced opacity.